# Error dentro de bucle que calcula promedio de notas e imprime datos en PDF, librería FPDF

Tags: php, mysqli

Lo que hace este código es imprimir las materias con calificaciones de un grupo de alumnos solicitado en PDF, una pagina impresa como boleta por cada alumno.
Dentro del bucle hay un `if` que compara una variable `$bandera` inicializada con el primer `idAlumno` recuperado de un `array asociativo` con el primer valor del `idAlumno` recuperado de la consulta, si coinciden imprime las notas del primer alumno y en el else imprime los datos de los demás alumnos.

Funciona bien esa parte, el problema es que cuando se quiere imprimir las notas de ciertos grupos, que ya tienen registradas calificaciones por lo que los `contadores` de registros en el bucle que funcionan de divisor para calcular promedio, deberian funcionar, marca este error:

`Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\pdfphp\reporteTiraBoleta.php on line 170

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\pdfphp\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\pdfphp\fpdf\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\pdfphp\fpdf\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\pdfphp\reporteTiraBoleta.php(273): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\pdfphp\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271`

Esto solo cuando se solicitan ciertos grupos, creo que seria error lógico el bucle imprimiendo la variable `$rpromedio`, acomodarla en otro lugar del bucle.
En el código comento algunas lineas.

```js
<?php
if( isset($_GET['periodo']) && isset($_GET['semestre']) && isset($_GET['grupo']) )  {

 $periodo = $_GET['periodo'];  //RECIBIMOS EL PARAMETRO POR URL : EL ID DE LA TABLA ALUMNO_GRUPO
 $semestre = $_GET['semestre'];
 $grupo = $_GET['grupo'];
}

//////////////////////////////////////CONSULTA TRAE TODAS LAS CALIFICACIONES DE TODOS LOS ALUMNOS PERYECIENTES A CIERTO GRUPO,
$consulta = "SELECT A.idAlumno, A.matricula, A.nombre, A.grupo, P.periodo, AG.parcial1 as p1mat, AG.inasisP1 as ina1mat, M.materia, M.idMateria, G.idGrupo, P.descripcion, A.semestre, G.capacitacion, M.areaComponente, P.descripcion FROM alumno A, alumno_grupo AG, grupos G, materias M, periodos P WHERE A.idAlumno = AG.idAlumno and G.idGrupo = AG.idGrupo and M.idMateria = G.materia and P.idPeriodo = G.periodo and P.periodo = $periodo and A.semestre = $semestre and A.grupo = $grupo ORDER BY A.nombre";
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$res=$mysqli->query($consulta);
$res2=$mysqli->query($consulta);

$pdf = new PDF();

$pdf->Addpage();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
    $pdf->Ln(18);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////// COLOCANDO ENCABEZADOS EN PAGINA
 $pdf->SetX(22);//posisionamos en 10 de x  DATOS DE LA PRIMERA HOJA RECUPERADA CON LAS  CALIFS DE UN ALUMNO
 $pdf->Cell(109,6,'UNIDAD ACADEMICA CURRICULAR',1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

 $pdf->SetX(132);//posisionamos en 10 de x
 $pdf->Cell(25,6,'INASISTENCIAS',1,0,'C',1);//

 $pdf->SetX(158);
 $pdf->Cell(24,6,'CALIFICACION',1,0,'C',1);

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //////////////////////////////////////////////// IMPRIMIENDO LOS VALORES DE LA TABLA //////////////////////////////

     $fila1 = $res->fetch_assoc();  //array asociativo de la consulta
     $bandera = $fila1['idAlumno']; //variable flag a la que se le asigna el idAlumno del primer registro 
     $suma = 0; //inicializando la variable que ira sumando las calificaciones
     $promedio = 0; //iniciaizando variable que almacenara el promedio
  
    $pdf->SetXY(19,30);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$fila1['matricula'],1,0,'C',1);

     //NOMBRE ALUMNO COLPLETO
    $pdf->SetX(47);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(100,5,$fila1['nombre'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

    //SEMESTRE
    $pdf->SetX(150);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(9,5,$fila1['semestre'],1,0,'C',1);

    //PERIODO
    $pdf->SetX(161);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(24,5,$fila1['descripcion'],1,0,'C',1);

    //CAPACITACION DONDE ESTA INSCRITO
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetX(78);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$fila1['capacitacion'],1,0,'C',1);

    //NUMERO DE GRUPO
    $pdf->SetX(120);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(8,5,$fila1['grupo'],1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Ln();

$pdf->Ln(4.7);   

$contador = 0; //contara los registros que tienen el mismo idAlumno (Las calificaciones que le corresponden a cada alumno)
while ($fila = $res2->fetch_assoc())  //recuperando con array asociativo los califs de la tabla
{
   $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);

  if ( $bandera ==  $fila['idAlumno'] ) { //si en los registros recuperados, cada idAlumno es igual a bandera
                                            //imprimir los califs que correcponden a ese alumno

   if ($fila['materia'] == 'TUTORIA GRUPAL') {  //SI LA MATERIA ES TUTORIA:
        if ( $fila['p1mat'] == 10 ) {  // Y SI ES 10
          $pdf->SetX(22);
            $pdf->Cell(109,6, $fila['materia'],1,0,'C');//
              $pdf->SetX(132);
                $pdf->Cell(25,6, $fila['ina1mat'],1,0,'C');//       
                  $pdf->SetX(158);
                    $pdf->Cell(24,6, $fila['p1mat']='AC',1,1,'C',0);   //IMPRIME AC EN LA BOLETA PDF
        } else {                                                        //SI NO
          $pdf->SetX(22);
            $pdf->Cell(109,6, $fila['materia'],1,0,'C');//
              $pdf->SetX(132);
                $pdf->Cell(25,6, $fila['ina1mat'],1,0,'C');//       
                  $pdf->SetX(158);
                    $pdf->Cell(24,6, $fila['p1mat']='NA',1,1,'C',0);     //IMPRIME NO ACREDITADO EN BOLETA PDF
                    }                                                  
                       } else {  
                                                                 
                          $pdf->SetX(22);   //SI NO ES TUTORIA IMPRIME LA CALIF EN NUMERO
                          $pdf->Cell(109,6, $fila['materia'],1,0,'C');//
                          $pdf->SetX(132);
                          $pdf->Cell(25,6, $fila['ina1mat'],1,0,'C');//       
                          $pdf->SetX(158);
                          $pdf->Cell(24,6, $fila['p1mat'],1,1,'C',0);  

                           //VERIFICACIÓN DEL CAMPO CAPACITACION PARA DESCARTAR EN EL CALCULO DEL PROMEDIO
                           //AQUELLOS REGISTROS CON ESTOS VALORES.
                           //si el campo "capacitacion del registro actual es: paraescolares o tutorias"
                          if ( ($fila['areaComponente'] == 'Paraescolares') || ($fila['areaComponente'] == 'Tutorias') ) {
                               $suma = $suma; //suma tendrra el valor anterior
                               $contador = $contador;  //contador tendra el valor anterior
                                     
                                
                             } else {
                               $valorFila = $fila['p1mat']; //una variable que guardara la calificacion
                               $suma = $suma + $valorFila; //variable de sumatoria, que agregara el $valorFila
                               $contador++; //incrementa el contador  
                              
                             }
                          }  // FIN ELSE NO ES TUTORIA

  }  //FIN IF BANDERA == AL PRIMER ALUMNO

  else { //si no corresponden imprime el resto de calificaciones recuperadas en hojas separadas
    //que sea un valor variable dependiendo el numero de filas de calificaciones que encuentre
  
  $promedio = $suma/$contador;  //AQUI MARCA UN ERRROR: DIVISION BY CERO
  $rpromedio = round($promedio,3);
  $contador = 0;
  $suma = 0;
  
    $pdf->Ln(3);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,'PROMEDIO:',1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->SetX(158);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6,$rpromedio,1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Ln(30);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(45,6,'Ing. Alma Rosa Delgado Pineda',1,0,'C',1);
   $pdf->Ln(8);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6,'Directora',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Ln(16);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,$date = date("d-m-Y"),1,0,'C',1);

   $pdf->Addpage();  //AGREGANDO PAGINA SIGUIENTE EN CASO QUE EL IDALUMNO NO SEA EL MISMO

   //MATRICULA
    $pdf->SetX(19);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$fila['matricula'],1,0,'C',1);

     //NOMBRE ALUMNO COLPLETO
    $pdf->SetX(47);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(100,5,$fila['nombre'],1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

    //SEMESTRE
    $pdf->SetX(150);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(9,5,$fila['semestre'],1,0,'C',1);

    //PERIODO
    $pdf->SetX(161);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(24,5,$fila['descripcion'],1,0,'C',1);

    //CAPACITACION DONDE ESTA INSCRITO
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetX(78);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$fila['capacitacion'],1,0,'C',1);

    //NUMERO DE GRUPO
    $pdf->SetX(120);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(8,5,$fila['grupo'],1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetX(22);//posisionamos en 10 de x  DATOS DE LA PRIMERA HOJA RECUPERADA CON LAS  CALIFS DE UN ALUMNO
    $pdf->Cell(109,6,'UNIDAD ACADEMICA CURRICULAR',1,0,'C',1);//colocando ancho de celda

    $pdf->SetX(132);//posisionamos en 10 de x
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,'INASISTENCIAS',1,0,'C',1);//

    $pdf->SetX(158);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6,'CALIFICACION',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Ln();

    $pdf->SetX(22);
    $pdf->Cell(109,6, $fila['materia'],1,0,'C');

    $pdf->SetX(132);//nombre alumno
    $pdf->Cell(25,6, $fila['ina1mat'],1,0,'C',0);

    $pdf->SetX(158);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6, $fila['p1mat'],1,1,'C',0); 
                       //SI LA MATERIA ES PARAESCOLAR O TUTORIA NO SE TOMA EN CUENTA PARA PROMEDIO 
                 if ( ($fila['areaComponente'] == 'Paraescolares') || ($fila['areaComponente'] == 'Tutorias') ) {
                               $suma = $suma; //suma tendrra el valor anterior
                               $contador = $contador;  //contador tendra el valor anterior
                                                                  
                             } else {
                               $valorFila = $fila['p1mat']; //una variable que guardara la calificacion
                               $suma = $suma + $valorFila; //variable de sumatoria, que agregara el $valorFila
                               $contador++; //incrementa el contador  
                              
                             }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
  } //fin else
      $bandera = $fila['idAlumno'];
} //fin while (fila = res)

    /*$promedio = $suma/$contador;
    $rpromedio = round($promedio,3);*/     //AQUI MARCA UN ERRROR: DIVISION BY CERO T FALTA DE VARIABLE $rpromedio
    $pdf->Ln(3);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,'PROMEDIO:',1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->SetX(158);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6,$rpromedio,1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Ln(30);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(45,6,'Ing. Jesus Sánchez',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Ln(8);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(24,6,'Director',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Ln(16);
    $pdf->SetX(132);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,$date = date("d-m-Y"),1,0,'C',1);

$pdf->Output();  //ERROR DE LINEA 276 AL IMPRIMIR FUERA DEL BUCLE LA VARIABLE $rpromedio

?>
```

Comment: Por lo que se puede observar a simple vista es que el if simpre cae cuando `contador = contador ó cuando contador = 0; `  no podrías hacer otra cosa en ese caso?

Comment: Corriste esa tira en tu gestor de base de datos? Sino lo has hecho, posiblemente sea un error allí.

Comment: Si la corri en mysql y las arroja bien las que en php no imprime. Creo que puede que sea el if como dice el compañero